# I cannot compile "out-of-the-box" - google's example cloud backend IOS client

Tags: google-app-engine

Why am I getting "duplicate symbol _kCloudBackendClientID" compiling the project "solutions-mobile-backend-starter-ios-client-master" from Google?

This is right out of the box - I have xCode 5.0.2 (5A3005)

I am trying out their Mobile Backend Starter... ugh so tedious to get this working.

Comment: duplicate symbols are _kCloudBackendClientID, _kCloudBackendClientSecret, _kCloudBackendChainName and _kCloudBackendServiceURL. It is saying they exist in both MessagesTableViewController.o and Constants.o.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 28 2014.. yes, the google app engine mobile backend starter for ios is a real pain in the a** to get working. I'm using XCode 5.1 and managed to get it all working after about 8 hours of trial and error.

The setup guide is here -

https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/ios/

There are a lot of steps required to get the push notification certificates and provisioning profiles and app id's setup properly. One stumbling block is that when doing development builds, XCode forces your bundle identifier to have ".dev" at the end. Be sure you have this in the provisioning profile that you create with the attached push notification certificate.

There are several things broken with the code. First the compiler error:

1) Change #include "Constants.m" to #include "Constants.h" in MessagesTableViewController.m

Now the runtime errors:

2) Add Splash1/2/3ViewController.h and .m to the project. If you don't do this you get a crash on startup related to some exception related to UIViewController

3) Implement this in CloudBackendIOSClientAppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
  fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{
/* copy-paste the code from the previous didReceiveRemoteNotification */

//add this
  if (handler)
    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);

}
```

This API seems to be new as of IOS7 and (I guess) is required to receive push notifications on IOS7.

The other thing I had to do was go into the app engine configuration on the app engine website. On the "Backends" tab, you have to make sure your 'worker' backend is started.

If you get all of this done properly you should be able to go down to the "Custom/Mobile Backend settings" tab, scroll to the bottom, and send a broadcast message successfully.

Hey Google people, if you are reading this you can compensate me with some free tech support on the next hurdles I have to jump through ;)